# Java – 2 dimensional Array with constructor and method

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, methods, constructor, void

I'm new to Java and have to create a method that prints out "A" for every even number within a two dimensional array (Project university). The result should look like this:

The result. Lines are just for better understanding

[image: The result. Lines are just for better understanding]

The main task says it should work with every field size n.
Given is a field variable `char[][] field;` and a constructor with a parameter `public Pattern(int n)`. The constructor is required.

**1.) First question:**

I'm not sure if I can access the variable field inside the constructor, because it is in its scope. Is there a possibility to declare the field size within the constructor, pass it to my method and finally print the whole class out with the desired result?

**2.) Second question:**

What would the alternative look like without a given constructor?

Here's my code:

```java
public class Pattern {

  char[][] field;

  public Pattern(int n) {
     if (n < 5) n = 5;
     if (n % 2 == 0) n = n + 1;
     field = new char[n][n];
  }

  public void fillArrayWithA() {
     for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {
         for (int j = 0; j <= 5; j++) { 
             if ((i + j) % 2 == 0) {
                 System.out.println('A');
             } else {
                 System.out.println(' ');
             }
         }
         System.out.println("\n");
      }
   }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
     Pattern firstex = new Pattern(5);
     firstex.fillArrayWithA();
     System.out.println(firstex);
  }
}
```

Code examples would be great!!

Comment: Why are you checking n size in constructor. Whatever be the n size you have to print A in even squares right? Provide clear explanation

Comment: you use constructor to initialize the variable. and that is in class so it's accessibility is in entire class if it's private or default

Comment: And the alternative will be like you take two parameters m, n and pass it to `fillArrayWithA()`

Comment: is the constructor code given as a requirement? If not, i don't understand your second question. If yes, the alternative would be to create a function to initialize `field` and call it in your `main` for example

Comment: You should use `System.out.print` and not `System.out.println`.

Comment: @DanieleTorino how does it matter ? It depends on user's choice

Comment: @Lokesh: if you want to get the correct pattern you cannot use `println` because doing so will output every character on a new line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my solution, I have removed the restrictions that the array needs to be square but it's easy to add that requirement back. I get the size of the array later by using the *length* attribute. I have also added a toString() method for printing the array.

```
public class Pattern {
  private char [][] field;

  public Pattern(int size) {
    field = new char [size][size];
  }

  public void fillField() {
    int size = field.length;
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
        int value = i+j + 1;
        field[i][j] = value % 2 == 0 ? 'A' : ' ';
      }
    }
  }

  public String toString() {
    int size = field.length;

    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(size * size);

    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
        builder.append(field[i][j]);
        builder.append(',');
      }
      builder.append('\n');
    }
    return builder.toString();
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Pattern p = new Pattern(5);
    p.fillField();
    System.out.print(p);
  }
}
```

To avoid a constructor then have the fillField take the size as parameter(s) and initialise the array there.

```
public void fillField(int size) {
  field = new char [size][size];

 ....
}
```

The best thing about having a constructor is that you know the member field is initialised before you use it.

Comment: Thank you Joakim for this clear solution. This looks like a more accurate way to do so, but my problem is still remaining. There is no way to get rid of the constructor as it appears in the exercise... Is there a solution closer to my given scenario?

Comment: I missed that the constructor must have a specific signature, I'll change my answer.

Comment: It worked out for me! Thanks a lot. I integrated the StringBuilder inside the fillField method after the for-loop. Yet im not quiet sure in which case I have to use the Stringbuilder method... but thanks anyway :)

Comment: I used the StringBuilder since I had a separate method for generating the string to print and it is an excellent class to use when building a string object from different parts, if you're doing System.out.print directly in fillField then you don't really need StringBuilder I guess. Please mark the answer as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a field with the dimension, or use `field.length`. Using `final` prevents further assignment to the fields. `this.n` allows to have a field with the same name as the parameter `n`.

```
  final char[][] field;
  final int n;

  public Pattern(int n) {
     n = Math.max(5, n) | 1; // If understandable
     this.n = n;
     field = new char[n][n];
  }

  public void fillArrayWithA() {
     for (int i = 0; i < field.length; i++) { // or n
         for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) { // or field[i].length
             field[i][j] = (i + j) % 2 == 1 ? 'A' : ' ';
```

Notice that `new int[3]` would have index values 0, 1, 2. Hence `i < n`.

Comment: `i + j % 2` -> `(i + j) % 2` or `(i + j) & 1`